# MSBuild error: MSB4062: Could not load Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc-Task

Tags: asp.net, msbuild

When compiling my ASP.NET web application in Visual Studio 2017, everything is working fine. But when I call msbuild.exe for compiling the application in the cmd window I get this error (sorry, it is in german):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(448,9):
error MSB4062: Die Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc-Aufgabe konnte nicht aus der
:\my\Sandboxes\2017\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.6.1\build\..\tools\Microsoft.Build
.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll-Assembly geladen werden. Die Datei oder Assembly
"Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden.
Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. Stellen Sie sicher, dass die
<UsingTask>-Deklaration korrekt ist, die Assembly und alle zugehörigen Abhängigkeiten
verfügbar sind und die Aufgabe eine öffentliche Klasse enthält, die Microsoft.Build
.Framework.ITask implementiert. [C:\my\Sandboxes\2017\WebApplication\WebApplication.csproj]
```

I tried deleting the packages folder, because it seems to me that some files are damaged there. Poorly this did not solve the Problem.

What is a UsingTask-Deklaration?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks, Volker

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is that I've got several versions of Visual Studio installed. So there are more than one msbuild.exe installed. The path variable on my system pointed to the wrong version of msbuild.exe.

Maybe this helps anyone else too...

Volker